# Parse Server Simple Mailgun Adapter 'verifyUserEmails' issue

Tags: heroku, mailgun, parse-server

I am using the [Parse Server Simple Mailgun Adapter](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter), and my Parse Server is working perfectly on Heroku. I am new to node.js and Express, but I installed the adapter on the root of the Parse Server via:

```
npm i parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter
```

This created a node_modules folder and essentially cloned the Github repository for the Mailgun Adapter. My index.js Parse Server configuration looks like:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  verifyUserEmails: true,
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://DATABASE',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'APPID',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'MASTERKEY', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'https://SERVER/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  publicServerURL: 'https://SERVER/parse',
  fileKey: process.env.FILE_KEY || 'FILEKEY',
  push: {
    ios: [
      {
        pfx: 'FILE.p12', // Dev PFX or P12
        bundleId: 'BUNDLE',
        production: false // Dev
      },
      {
        pfx: 'FILE.p12', // Prod PFX or P12
        bundleId: 'BUNDLE',  
        production: true // Prod
      }
    ]
  },
  emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
      fromAddress: 'EMAIL@DOMAIN',
      domain: 'DOMAIN',
      apiKey: 'KEY',
    }
  },
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
```

The server works perfectly when commenting out the `verifyUserEmails` key. With it, the server will not work. The Mailgun adapter does not work regardless. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set up the email adapter?

Take a look at : https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

Email verification and password reset

Verifying user email addresses and enabling password reset via email requries an email adapter. As part of the parse-server package we provide an adapter for sending email through Mailgun. To use it, sign up for Mailgun, and add this to your initialization code:

```
var server = ParseServer({
  ...otherOptions,
  // Enable email verification
  verifyUserEmails: true,
  // The public URL of your app.
  // This will appear in the link that is used to verify email addresses and reset passwords.
  // Set the mount path as it is in serverURL
  publicServerURL: 'https://example.com/parse',
  // Your apps name. This will appear in the subject and body of the emails that are sent.
  appName: 'Parse App',
  // The email adapter
  emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
      // The address that your emails come from
      fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
      // Your domain from mailgun.com
      domain: 'example.com',
      // Your API key from mailgun.com
      apiKey: 'key-mykey',
    }
  }
});
```

You can also use other email adapters contributed by the community such as parse-server-sendgrid-adapter or parse-server-mandrill-adapter.

OR

Create your own in cloud code using mailgun-js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js

```
var api_key = '[SECRET_API_KEY]';
var domain = '[DOMAIN_HERE]';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});

Parse.Cloud.define('testemail', function(req, res) {
  var data = {
    from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
    to: 'foo@bar.com',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
  };

  mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    console.log(body);
  });

  res.success('Email Sent!');
});
```

Comment: The issue was that it just took time after verifying for it to work. The code in my original message worked after trying it later.

Answer (score 0):

The real reason why this happens is because you need to include the `appName` in your server initialization (this drove me crazy for hours)

`appName: 'yourAppName',`